# rosjava_android+opencv=Fuerte?

Tags: opencv, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm hoping to use opencv in a rosjava android environment. I've had a hard time building these packages together, and/or integrating their pre-compiled versions into an eclipse project I can code/build against. Not surprising, as I've been pulling from unreleased/experimental source repos :)

Anyway, is there an ETA for when a semi-stable version of these packages will be released? Maybe alongside Fuerte? :)

Thanks,
-Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31757/rosjava_android+opencv=fuerte?/) by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on ROS Answers with karma: 481 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As for rosjava_core and android_core (I was not aware of the wiki page rosjava_android until now, deleted it, see android_core instead) I'm working toward a stable release before ROSCon. However, time is running short...

As for opencv, I have no idea. But, I'd love to see that happen. Maybe something like SimpleCV for Android.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on 2012-04-16**:
Thanks for the info, Damon. As per the pre-release docs, should I expect that maven/gradle will be the new build environment? (i.e., rosmake/eclipse projects are not supported?)

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-17**:
rosmake is not supported (replaced by gradle), but Eclipse is.